# application created with New-MsolServicePrincipal not showing up in Azure portal

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I'm using PowerShell to register an application in Azure AD:

```
New-MsolServicePrincipal `
-DisplayName $appDisplayName `
-Addresses $addys `
-ServicePrincipalNames @($spn)
```

The command completes successfully with the following output:

```
The following symmetric key was created as one was not supplied 7JEl99ZJ1ZWDS...

DisplayName           : My App
ServicePrincipalNames : {https://blah.com/myapp, db286381-a896-4290-8179-...}
ObjectId              : 0a197d26-49b8-4e9b-8739-...
AppPrincipalId        : db286381-a896-4290-8179-...
TrustedForDelegation  : False
AccountEnabled        : True
Addresses             : {Microsoft.Online.Administration.RedirectUri}
KeyType               : Symmetric
KeyId                 : c3a709e5-7d23-4d1a-842b-...
StartDate             : 11/24/2014 6:30:19 PM
EndDate               : 11/24/2015 6:30:19 PM
Usage                 : Verify
```

I can also use Get-MsolServicePrincipal to verify that the Service Principal now exists.  But when I go to https://manage.windowsazure.com and look in my Azure AD tenant under applications, it's not there.  Shouldn't I be able to see the app in the portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The applications you see in the portal are projections of the Application entities in the directory. The apps created via powershell are only ServicePrincipals I believe. For a detailed explanation of the difference between the two see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn132633.aspx

Comment: Thanks Vittorio, that makes sense.  So is it possible to create an application entity via PowerShell?

Comment: NP! Not possible with today's cmdlets, the Application entity was introduced in the service after their release

Comment: Found [this suggestion](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/5629587-add-application-s-serviceprincipal-using-powershel) on the Azure AD feedback site.